# Chat (like Facebook) source code/component for ASP.NET Website

Tags: asp.net, chat

I want to add a chat feature (like Facebook chat) on my ASP.NET Project. All chat functions are like FB Chat. Example:

- blink browser 's title to alert user when new message come
- do not close when reload page
- ...

My project have users database and user will login to use chat feature.

Hope someone tell me source code or component or any information about that.

Thanks !

Comment: google for "c# code for chat application in asp.net" you can also add "signalr" to the keywords. There are lots of code samples and components. e.g. this one http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/chatr-just-another-chat-application-using-signalr/ another one here http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETAJAXWebChat-c4c9b8fe/view/SourceCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this one: JabbR. [Live site here](http://jabbr.net), [Source code here](https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR). Try out the Live site and if you like it, download the source from github.